# Namespace prefix sap for aggregation-role on Property is not defined

Tags: java, odata, sapui5, olingo, java-persistence-api

I am trying to view metadata using URL localhost:8080/a_final/a.svc/$metadata. This is JPA based project and uses olingo OData .

I am getting below error - [image]

There is no clear answer on web. It would be good if I can know about the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

are you using WebIDE or Eclipse?

This error means, that somthing went wrong while bootstraping the ui5 resources.

Check your index.html.

You cand load the ui5 resources online via:

```
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
       data-sap-ui-preload="async" 
       data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
       data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
       data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
       data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
       "<NAMESPACE>": "<FOLDER>"
  }' >
  </script>
```

Or you can load it local via eclipse plugin:

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
       data-sap-ui-preload="async" 
       data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
       data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
       data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
       data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
      "<NAMESPACE>": "<FOLDER>"
  }' >
  </script>
```

Comment: I am using both WebIDE and Eclipse. Where my UI5 code reside only on WebIDE not on eclipse.
The above issue with server side code and it resides in eclipse where I am trying to get the metadata of server side classes and entity. we are using Java Persistance API with HANA db and ODATA to intract with UI5.